# How to create nice forms with active_scaffold gem on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activescaffold

1. How to override Active Scaffold form fields for date or time?
   (datepicker and calendar_date_select didn't work for me, probably
   because I'm using the activescaffold gem)
2. How to override Active Scaffold form to select from a list of resources in the
   database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was struggling this question until I figured it out. Here's an example:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  attr_accessible :name
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players 
  attr_accessible :thedate, :thetime, :winnername
end

class GamesController < ApplicationController
  active_scaffold :game do |conf|
    # do nothing in this example
  end
end

module GamesHelper

  # date select
  def game_thedate_form_column (record, options)
    date_select :record, :thedate, options
  end

  # time select
  def game_thetime_form_column (record, options)
    time_select :record, :thetime, options
  end

  # select from database resources
  def game_winnername_form_column (record, options)
    select_tag :winnername, options_for_select(get_players_names_arr(record)), options
  end

  def get_players_names_arr(game)
    names = []
    game.players.each do |player|
      names << player.name
    end
    names 
  end

end
```